# Google apps single sign on removed but change password still pointing to the old system

Tags: single-sign-on, google-apps

We had setup external single sign on for our company for google apps, tried it out and it didn't fit our needs. We are not paying for the service, though it is still integrated with our Google products we use (IE: trying to change passwords).

I would like to know how to safely remove the integration or delete it.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to flag this as `google-apps` rather than App Engine as they are two different products. As for setting up external single sign on I can only imagine you would just undo all the changes you made to enable it.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the suggestion, it would be more appropriate to use google-apps.

Comment: List here all steps you took to reproduce this. Otherwise its not fit for s.o. (thou im intetested in what causes this)

Comment: The steps that were done 1) In the google apps admin console, go to security settings and find SSO settings 2) In the SSO settings, enable it by clicking on the checkbox, and add values to all text boxes like ACS URL, logout URL, and also add a certificate that you download from your IdP 3) Check if SAML sso works...for me it worked. Meaning now when i go to login to my google apps account, instead of Google authenticating me its my new IdP Now step 4) go to admin console again and uncheck the check box at the top. So now google should authenticate me and logout URL should be changed. Its not.